# Django app + 3rd party' s template directory

Tags: django, django-templates, pypi

I' ve a django application to which i' m writing a 3rd party application which is getting placed in the virtualenv' s lib/python2.7/site-packages/appname directory . It has also template files, but the django application itself does not find it by default.

What is the best way to write the 3rd party app in a way that the django app will find the template directory (in the easiest way)?

The 3rd party app has the following structure:

```
appdir/
    views.py
    forms.py
    templates/
```

. The django app has the following related settings:

```
TEMPLATES['APP_DIRS'] = True
INSTALLED_APPS has the 3rd party app
```

.

Of course it' s an easy workaround to add the 3rd party app' s location to TEMPLATES['DIRS'], but i' m rather interested in the best technique.

Django: 1.11.16
Python: 2.7.9

.

Answer (score 0):

You should create one folder with the same name as your app inside templates folder and place all the templates inside of it. In above case the folder should be named `appdir`. If you set `APP_DIRS` to `True` this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For example if your app name is `test` then in your root project create a folder `test` then create folder `templates` in it. Then override whatever file that you wants to override.

for example if you want to override `index.html` of app `test` then:

```
BASE_DIR (project root)
  - test
     - templates
        - index.html
```